# Data download functionality for API response Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, download

I have an API response where I'm getting data as comma separated values and not as JSON objects. I need to export this data into CSV file. Can someone please suggest a method to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could parse your data to a JSON-object:

```
  const apiData: string = 'value1,value2,value3';
  const data: string[] = apiData.split(',');
```

And then you could use a combination of [xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) and [fileSaver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver)

Pseudocode:

```
    const worksheet: xlsx.WorkSheet = xlsx.utils.json_to_sheet(data);
    const workbook: xlsx.WorkBook = {
      Sheets: { [worksheetName]: worksheet },
      SheetNames: [worksheetName]
    };

    const buffer = xlsx.write(workbook, { 'csv', type: 'array' });
    const blob = new Blob([buffer], { type: 'text/comma-separated-values' });

    fileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'filename.csv');
```